# Unable to match a sample emoji. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, emoji

[Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs) is a Unicode block containing meteorological and astronomical symbols, emoji characters largely for compatibility with Japanese telephone carriers' implementations of Shift JIS, and characters originally from the Wingdings and Webdings fonts found in Microsoft Windows.

The Unicode range specified by the referenced Wikipedia article is `U+1F300..U+1F5FF`

But if I pick an emoji from the list and do a regex match, it fails.

```
var a = "";
var matched = a.match(/[\u1F300-\u1F5FF]/);
```

`matched` is always null. Why is that? Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: JavaScript strings don't support real Unicode, just UCS-2.

Comment: You cannot use 5 character Unicode codepoints in JavaScript like this. That is effectively a match for the character class `\u1f30` or anything from `0` to `\u1f5f` or the character `f`. In ECMAScript 6 you should be able to use `[\u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}]`.

Comment: I should note that when you use the braced form for the Unicode escape sequence, you need to pass the `u` flag to the regular expression, such as: `/[\u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}]/u`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

Javascript has had a [Unicode Problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) for a while. Unicode Codepoints that lie outside the range U+0000...U+FFFF are known as **astral codepoints**, and are problematic because they are not easy to match via a regex:

```
// `` is an astral symbol because its codepoint value
//  of U+1F30D is outside the range U+0000...U+FFFF
//  Astral symbols do not work with regular expressions as expected
var regex = /^[bc]$/;
console.log(
    regex.test('a'),  // false
    regex.test('b'),  // true
    regex.test('c'),  // true
    regex.test('')  // false (!)
);
console.log(''.match(regex)); // null (!)
```

The reason is because this one astral codepoint is actually made up of *two parts*, or more precisely of two "*code units*", and these two code units combine together to form the character.

```
console.log("\u1F30D")      // Doesn't work
console.log("\uD83C\uDF0D") //
```

The astral symbol  is actually made up of two code units:  = **U+D83C** + **U+DF0D**!
So if you wanted to match this astral symbol, you would have to use the following regex and matcher:

```
var regex = /^([bc]|\uD83C\uDF0D)$/;
console.log(
    regex.test('a'),  // false
    regex.test('b'),  // true
    regex.test('c'),  // true
    regex.test('\uD83C\uDF0D')  // true
);
console.log('\uD83C\uDF0D'.match(regex)); // { 0: "", 1: "", index: 0 ... }
```

*All* astral symbols have this decomposition. Surprised? Well perhaps you should be – this doesn't happen often! It only happens with *astral codepoints* which are *rarely used*. Most codepoints used by myself and others across the world are not astral – they're in the range U+0000...U+FFFF – so we don't typically see this issue. Emojis are a new exception to this rule – all emojis are astral symbols and thanks to social media, their usage is becoming increasingly popular across the world.

Using code units like this is an *implementation detail* of Unicode that was unfortunately exposed to Javascript programmers. It can easily cause confusion for programmers as it is unclear whether to use the character verbatim () or to instead use the code unit decomposition (**U+D83C** + **U+DF0D**) whenever string functions like `match`, `test`, ... are used; or whenever regexes and string literals are used. However language designers and implementers and working hard to improve things.

#### The Solution

A recent addition to ECMAScript 6 (ES6) was the [introduction of a `u` flag](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex) to regular expression matching. This allows you to match by *codepoint*, rather than matching by *code units* (default).

```
var regex = /^[bc]$/u; // <-- u flag added
console.log(
    regex.test('a'), // false
    regex.test('b'), // true
    regex.test('c'), // true
    regex.test('')  // true <-- it now works!
);
```

By using the `u` flag, you don't have to worry about whether or not your codepoint is an astral codepoint and you don't have to convert to and from code units. The `u` flag makes regular expression work the intuitive way - even for emojis! However, not every version of Node.js and not every Browser supports this new feature. To support all environments, you could use a library like [regenerate](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regenerate).